# Correct Matplotlib math font size in classic style

Tags: python, css, matplotlib, fonts

I have seen quite some threads about this problem, but I can't seem to make it work. If you add any mathematical equations anywhere on the plot, it is a lot smaller than the normal text and greek letters (especially when you have a fraction) are even smaller. I tried to modify the matplotlibrc in order to make standard font size bigger (the standard seems to be 10 pts.), but it says, I have to move it to a special location to have permanent effect, which I cant find. Is there a way I can change the font size of the mathematical formulas dynamically (i.e. when I create a new plot)? I would need your help. I am currently running version 2.1.0 of matplotlib and overall I am running python over anaconda (on a Mac). This is the output:

[image: output]
Note that I'm using the `style.use('classic')` in order to fit the desired overall style of the plot. If I do not use this style, the output is fine. Is there any solution that would still allow me to use this style?

I will put you an exemplary code below, so you can see for yourself how small the font of the greek letters (left axis) gets

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('classic')
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
y = [4140,3980,3820,3660,3500,3340,3180,3030,2870,2720,2562,2408,2266,2114,1962,1812,1668,1522,1386,1254,1138,1145,1188,1273,1358,1454,1547,1639,1732,1818,1904]
plt.plot(x,y,'g',label='Salzsäure',linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel(r'Elektrische Leitfähigkeit $\sigma$ in $\frac{\mu S}{cm}$')
plt.xlabel('Volumen 0.1M NaOH in mL')
plt.title('Titration einer Salzsäure unbekannter Konzentration')
plt.annotate('Äquivalenzpunkt', xy=(20,1138), xytext=(20,2300),
arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black',shrink=0.05),
)
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True,color='k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Any chance you can share a screenshot of this?

Comment: Why are you using `style.use('classic')`? If you remove that it should work fine.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes that is true, but some styles are unfit for some graphs (in my opinion). What do I then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the line

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] =  "dejavusans"
```

*after* setting the style, you should get the desired output. Note that fractions are *always* smaller, you cannot do much about that.

[image]